# CDO Corrupt PDF Attachment

Tags: asp-classic, legacy-code, cdo.message

What is the main problem that causes corrupt PDF attachments using **Classic ASP** CDO?

This is the error message when trying to open the document:

*There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (109).*

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted PDF attachment? Is it not opening? Is is scrambled? Got any error messages?

Comment: See updated answer for error message, thanks

Comment: Are you sure the PDF you attach is in itself okay? Can you open it without any errors?

Comment: Yes, the generated pdf on the server is working correctly, it is only the attachment that is corrupt...

Comment: How large is the PDF file? Running into size restrictions from the mailserver perhaps? Have you tried to attach a small non-generated PDF file to see if that comes through?

Comment: It varies from 200kb to 300kb... Will have a look now and let you know.

Comment: It is definitely not the file size restriction, i have sent mail larger than this... any other ideas coz I am lost?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9724/discussion-between-guido-gautier-and-marc-uberstein)

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to send email? CDOSYS, CDONTS, third party component?

Are you sending immediately or having the mail put in the pick up folder? If you use the pick up folder option then there is a known problem where period characters are removed if at the beginning of the line which could cuase corruption, see http://support.microsoft.com/?id=286358.

If using CDOSYS then I have read issues of encoding problems. I think CDOSYS does binary encoding by default in some systems. You can try changing to Base64 by changing your attachment encoding like this...

```
objAttachment.ContentTransferEncoding = "base64"
```

If that doesn't work your problems could probably be solved by using a different mail component such as [w3jmail](http://www.dimac.net/) (free for Classic ASP version).

Answer (score 0):

For CDONTS it is UUEncoding by default and that is probably not supported anymore by the mail client
.
To make it base64 encoding you need to attach the file as below.

```
objCDO.AttachFile fullfilepath, attachmentfilename, 1
```

The 1 being Base 64 vs the default 0 of UUEncoding.